# Music reactive LEDs

Tags: led, transistors, sound

I want to make a bigger project, but I have run in to a problem that I do not understand. I want to make an LED flash to music, for use in a bigger project. I have looked at about 20 different tutorials and googled my fingers off, because I cannot make it work.

I am using a 2N3904 transistor like him. I have tried with several jack sticks. I am simply lost, please help.

Schematic:
[image]

Picture:
[image]

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: I don't know, but I have tried everything, and I cannot understand why it is not working.

Comment: Then how can we answer your question if you don't know what it is?

Comment: As a bare minimum, please supply us with a diagram or schematic, else we cannot help you.

Comment: I have added some additional information.

Comment: Is the LED connected with the right polarity? Is it working at all? I would also add a couple of resistors - in series to LED and to the transistor gate.

Comment: It does work, if I touch the base with the collector side, the LED lights up.

Comment: What voltage is the battery?

Comment: It's powered with 3.3V from arduino, there is a resistor before the LED so it won't fry, that resistor is 100 ohm.

Comment: Most likely audio not getting about the 0.7V needed on the base of the transistor.

Comment: How can I boost it?

Comment: You can't without amplifier. Just find another audio source with higher signal amplitude. But first you should measure it to make sure it is the case.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have an oscilloscope, I will try another audio source.

Comment: Use a series resistor with the base.  Otherwise you will probably kill the transistor.

Comment: Yay it's finally working now, I used my laptop as an audio source and that works. Though it is only lighting ever so slightly, will I need an amplifier to make it bright, if so would an op amp work?

Comment: Yes, an OP amp is the way to go. You can even use current feedback from the LED to your audio source with just one extra resistor or just boost the voltage in open-loop going into the base of your transistor via a resistor.

Comment: I am a little confused, do I not need an OP amp?

Comment: Preferably yes, or higher voltage to drive the transistor with.

Comment: @RasmusTollund Please read the help section on how to ask  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Questions must be clear. This isn't really isn't a great site if your an entry level hobbyist. "This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts." If you need help learning electronics, there are some great sites on the internet to help you do so. Typically people that post here already have a background in electronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic problems with your circuit.

1. The transistor needs at least 0.6V to turn on. Any audio signal with a peak voltage below this won't light the LED at all.

You can solve this problem by using a voltage divider which raises the DC Base voltage up close to 0.6V.

2. The audio source will probably have a capacitor on its output to remove any DC bias that may be present. Unfortunately, when the signal peaks *do* get large enough to turn on the transistor on, its Base will draw current and charge up this capacitor, creating a negative bias voltage that turns the transistor off until the capacitor discharges again (which will take a very long time because there is no discharge path).

This effect can be reduced by providing a path to ground for the capacitor to discharge into, and adding a resistor in series with the Base to reduce the peak current.

The following circuit has been found to work reasonably well:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwCyPN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 and R4 create a voltage divider with a ratio of 5.7:1, dropping 3.3V down to 0.58V. This is enough to just barely turn the transistor on, so the LED will glow weakly with no signal. Any signal will now cause the transistor to turn on harder and make the LED glow brighter.

R2 reduces Base current during positive peaks of the signal waveform, reducing the amount of charge stored in the audio source's coupling capacitor. R4 provides a discharge path for this charge during the rest of the waveform. As R4 is much lower than R2, the capacitor will only build up a small bias voltage that doesn't affect the LED brightness much.

Note that even with these improvements this circuit will never produce maximum possible brightness, because it only turns the LED on during positive peaks of the audio waveform.